# How to hide Fields and Strike-through Legends when the data is empty or Zero in Pie/Polar/Doughnut Chart?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

Following is my resultant chart

[image]

Here the value of legends Happy and Very Happy is 0, hence it is overlapping each other and unable to read. So, How can I hide these values and strike through the legends while loading itself like in the below image? And yes, it is a dynamically loaded chart.

[image]

Link - [Reference Pie Chart](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#PieChart)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this answer hoping that, it will be helpful for someone later. You can also post a better solution if found.

After some deep diving into the library the files, I realised that is there are no direct answers to my question. But we can achieve that by emptying the label text in case of 0 data values.

For that, we must edit the chart options as follows,

```
public pieChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        formatter: (value, ctx) => {
          const label = ctx.chart.data.labels[ctx.dataIndex];
          if (ctx.dataset.data[ctx.dataIndex] > 0)
            return label + " : " + ctx.dataset.data[ctx.dataIndex];
          else
            return "" // retun empty if the data for label is empty
        },
      }
    },
    showLines: true,
    spanGaps: true,
    cutoutPercentage: 1,
    rotation: 15, // rotate the chart
  };
```

Here in the function returns empty value in case the data for the corresponding label is 0. Also I rotate the chart 15deg to make the labels horizontal align in most cases.

Reference - [Chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/)

Hence I achieved a better view to the user and the overlapping issues are resolved. Thanks.